# How to loop through Gridview and retrieve column value?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am using a Gridview

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvLoanUtilization" .....  </asp:GridView>
```

At run time, this is populated by a stored procedure:

```
  DataTable dt = SP.GetDataSet();
  this.gvLoanUtilization.DataSource = dt;
        this.gvLoanUtilization.DataBind();
```

Now, I want to loop through this gridview and check the value of a certain column of each row, how can I achieve this?

Comment: why don't you iterate over the data source before you bind it? Iterating through a datatable should be easier then getting all rows in a grid.
the question is: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Macro, based on a column value I want to set the whole row "Readonly"

Answer (score 1):

The RowDataBound event occurs when a data row is bound to data in a GridView control. You need to use `onrowdatabound="gvLoanUtilization_RowDataBound"` and inside that function you can check and perform any operation on data.

Here is the example, in which if the `age>=35` then it'll styled the background color to blue and a text to white:

```
protected void gvLoanUtilization_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int age =Convert.ToInt32( e.Row.Cells[3].Text);
        if (age >= 35)
        {
            e.Row.BackColor =System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#4F81BD");
            e.Row.ForeColor =System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
        }
    }
}
```